# EDT timezone works but same does not work for IST in Moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am able to convert below object to moment

```
var dateStr = "Tue Dec 06 00:00:00 EDT 2022";
var momentDateFormatted = moment(dateStr).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
alert(momentDateFormatted);   //07-14-2014
```

But this doesnt work for below code

```
var dateStr1 = "Tue Dec 06 00:00:00 IST 2022"; 
var momentDateFormatted1 = moment(dateStr1).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
alert(momentDateFormatted1); // Invalid date
```

}

only difference is **EDT** and **IST**. nothing else.

Why would that not work? Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/markd116/kj5nzz4w/